# Optimized data sort - software r

Tags: r

this is my first post, so please be polite if I might get sth wrong.

I have a set of data that I want to sort in a specific way using the software r.
It is a non-quadratic matrix of tasks (>100) that require specific components (>100) of specific material (1, 2, 3, or 4). I want to figure out, which tasks can be executed as a group because they require the same components. That's easy. But I want to optimize it, means that components with a low-value material (1) can be "upgraded" to a higher value material (2, 3 or 4) if that decreases the number of groups.
I could only manage to sort the data while upgrading all materials, but that's not what I want.

My minimum example looks like this:

```
1 0 0 2 0 4 0  
2 2 4 0 0 1 1  
0 4 4 0 0 3 0  
1 3 0 1 1 0 4  
4 2 1 0 4 1 2
```

0 means that this component is not required.

I hope I could describe my problem clearly enough.
thanks a lot in advance for your suggestions
Miguel

Comment: Could you show us what is the result of sorting on your example?

Comment: I put the variance of the materials in the components themselves so that I have a binary matrix with only 0 and 1. Sorting it with any algorithm is easy, like hclust. Using this hierarchical sort algorithm is nice because I can visualize how my groups look like and how I could probably group them further. Like an ordinary dendrogram.

Comment: is that what you mean? Or what result I wish to have in that example matrix?